# What's the best deployment strategy for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, deployment, webdeploy

I work for an ISV and we have a vanilla ASP.NET (no mvc) web application which we deploy to our customer sites.

We're currently doing it via xcopy and IIS manually.

What's the best technology to use to deploy it? ClickOnce? WebDeploy? Something else?

Tips appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebDeploy FTW.

Check out [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx) excellent article/video from Scott Hanselman.

Handles config transformations as well as the painful task of database deployments.

Comment: I thought Web Deploy was for server farms on a local domain. How does it work with deploying to customer sites? Are there any issues there?

Comment: @WOPR - Web Deploy has many different modes/ways to deploy within its framwork. If you want to deploy to a Web Farm with WD, install MS Web Farm framework. If you want to deploy to a client server (single server) from your machine (VS), install MS Web Platform installer. These are simple things to do, and plenty of resources are available. Here, we use "FTP" deploy to publish the files to the server, and we still deploy the DB manually. If you're client is fussy about their servers (dont want you installing extra software), you might need to do the same.